# Search and replace items within an ini file, using python2.7, perl, sed within a bash one-liner

Tags: bash, perl, ini

Today i stumbled upon a little problem i could not solve (easily). Basicly i want to update an item within a ini file, with simple pre installed tools only (bash, sed, perl or python). Sadly installing tools from the internet is not an option.

But i could not figure out a solution by myself. I have tried perl search and replace, sed and python but nothing leads to a nice bash one-liner i was looking for. Known information is only the user (e.g john) and i want to change the displayName of John (only) leaving everything else as it was. I think a perl call could do the trick, but i was not able to figure it out. Anyway, how would you approach the development of such a perl statement?

```
; last modified 1 April 2001 by John Doe
; Syntax:
; user = john
; displayName = 12345

[sectionA]
user=notChange
displayName=noChange
[sectionB]
user = john
displayName = 12345
.....
```

I would like to parse the file for "john" and then replace whatever is written behind "displayName="

Thank you guys for all the great answers! I tested them all and all seem to work as expected, and provide hints for me to learn so one time i can solve such a task by myself :) ! Thank you for your time and effort!!

Comment: The `displayName = ` is at multiple places (section) -- should it become 'john` everywhere?

Comment: well that was one of the difficulties i faced, only change the displayName where the preceeding userName = john.

Comment: Hang on -- so you mean only change it where it's `12345`, in `sectionB`? Only in those sections where the username is what is given at the beginning, in this case `john`?  (And is there only one such section?)

Comment: Yes, in that case i only want to change sectionB. There might be multiple sections containing same the user name, which sould be changed as well. (sorry, forgot to mention that in my question)

Comment: Ah. Updated to that (what I had originally changed every instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**   See end for a version which does not rely on order of lines within `[section]`

---

For input file *exactly* as shown

```
perl -pE'
    /;\s*user\s*=\s*(.*)/ and $user = $1; 
    ($u) = /^user\s*=\s*(.*)/;
    s/^\s*displayName\s*=\s*\K.*/$user/ if $f; 
    $f = $u eq $user
' file
```

Shown over multiple lines for readability, explanation line by line:

1. Capture the user name to be used for the file. Comes in the beginning on lines with `;`
2. Capture the username in a section (`user` starts the line), or `$u` stays `undef`
3. Change the value for `displayName` --- if the flag `$f` is set (on the previous line)
4. Set that `$f` flag to the result of comparison: true (1) if `$u` (is set and) matches `$user`

The program works through the lines of a file as follows:

- on `;` line the `$user` is set while on other lines regex doesn't match and nothing happens
- on lines starting with `user` (in sections) that section's user name is set (`$u`), on other lines `$u` becomes `undef`
- the `displayName` change happens if `$f` is true, and this was set on the previous line if `$u` was set and was indeed equal to the `$user` -- otherwise it's false.
- so `displayName` changes on a line following the `user =` line, and if on that (previous) line the user `$u` was equal to the one found in the beginning (`$user`).

This freely uses variables which are often `undef` and would trigger numerous warnings with `-w`; contrary to my practice I drop it here, for simplicity (instead of testing with `define`).

The code assumes that

- user name definition comes before its use on a line starting with `;` (at the beginning)
- in a section the `user =` line comes before the `displayName =` line --- but see below
- the `displayName` lines that come later start with the phrase, with nothing before it
- the `user =` lines in sections start with `user`
- change `displayName =` only in the section with the username captured at the beginning

To overwrite the input file (change it *in-place*) add `-i` option, or `-i.bak` to keep a backup. To create a new file with changes redirect output, `perl -wpe'...' file > new_file`

---

One necessary and possibly prohibitive assumption above is that the line `user =` comes before the line `displayName =`, what is in general not a rule in an `ini` file.

In order to relax that we need to *first collect lines* for `user` and `displayName` for each section, and once both are on hand work it out and only then write them out

```
perl nE'
    /;\s*user\s*=\s*(.*)/ and $user = $1; 
    if ( 2 == ( @k = keys %sec ) ) { 
        say "$_ = ", ( $sec{user} eq $user ? $user : $sec{$_} ) for @k;
        %sec = () 
    } else { 
        /^(user|displayName)\s*=\s*(.*)/ and $sec{$1} = $2
    }
    print $_ unless /^(user|displayName)/;
    END { 
        say "$_ = ", ( $sec{user} eq $user ? $user : $sec{$_} ) for keys %sec
    }
' file
```

(Making this nicer, in particular getting rid of that code-repeating END block, is left as an exercise)

If this code needs to live inside a bash script and no extra files can be had on disk, then so be it; but otherwise please write it as a nice script.

Comment: Very nice. But this assumes that the user line in a section is always before the displayName line. Ini files usually have no specific order in the sections. Maybe something to check before doing it on a huge or on many file.

Comment: @mivk Hah!  A good point, thank you. A quiet little assumption that was, added it to the list.  I do go with "_file exactly as shown_" as there were too many unspecified parts. Will relax (fix) that when I get to it.

Comment: @mivk Fixed.  Added a version which doesn't care for order

Answer (score 3):

This seems to do what you are after:

```
perl -0777 -ne '@sections = split /^\[/m; foreach (@sections) { if (/^\s*user\s*=\s*john\s*$/m) {s/^(\s*displayName\s*=).*/$1 is now Greta/mi} } print join("[", @sections); ' /tmp/inifile
```

Or in a more readable version:

```
perl -0777 -ne '                                    # -0777 makes it slurp the whole file
  @sections = split /^\[/m;                       # split on "[" if it's at the start of a line
  foreach (@sections) {
    if ( /^\s*user\s*=\s*john\s*$/m ) {              # if the section contains user=john
      s/^(\s*displayName\s*=).*/$1 call me Greta/mi;  # give him a new displayname
    }
  }
  print join("[", @sections);     # print all, adding back the "[" we removed for split.
' /tmp/inifile
```

The output:

> ```
> ; last modified 1 April 2001 by John Doe
> ; Syntax:
> ; user = john
> ; displayName = 12345
>
> [sectionA]
> user=notChange
> displayName=noChange
> [sectionB]
> user = john
> displayName = call me Greta
> ```

Or to do it on files "in-place", with almost the same line:

```
perl -0777 -i.bak -pe '@sections = split /^\[/m; foreach (@sections) { if (/^\s*user\s*=\s*john\s*$/m) {s/^(\s*displayName\s*=).*/$1 call me Greta/mi} } $_=join("[", @sections); ' /tmp/inifile
```

Which gives:

```
diff /tmp/inifile /tmp/inifile.bak
```

> ```
> 11c11
> < displayName = call me Greta
> ---
> > displayName = 12345
> ```

And to specify the user and display name on the command-line instead of having them hard-coded, add them before the file name and add a `BEGIN` block:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'BEGIN{$u=shift; $n=shift}
  @sections = split /^\[/m; foreach (@sections) { if (/^\s*user\s*=\s*$u\s*$/m) {s/^(\s*displayName\s*=).*/$1 $n/mi} } print join("[", @sections); '
  "john" "My name is Bond..." /tmp/inifile
```

Comment: But the name is not `john`, that's just an example here -- the actual name is given on the `; user = ` line in the beginning.

Comment: @ikegami: Thank you! Yes, of course 07 is not > 0400, and this worked accidentally because there is no \x07 character in the file. Corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

Something similar to this should do the trick:

```
$ perl -i.bak -pe'$user = $1 if /user = (.*)/; s/(displayName = ).*/${1}newid/ if $user eq "john"' foo.ini
```

Comment: But the name is not `john`, that's just an example here -- the actual name is given on the `; user = ` line in the beginning.